# Trying to open an editor in RCP

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I am developing an RCP application where I am trying to open the graphiti editor through tool bar menu ,but its giving me the exceptions mentioned below...
please help

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isLegal(Assert.java:63)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isLegal(Assert.java:47)
org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.findElements(ModelServiceImp.
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3112)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$21(WorkbenchPage.java:3034)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$8.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3016)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3012)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2976)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2959)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:827)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:432)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:628)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:826)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:802)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:290)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

Comment: Post the code how do you try to open it. Do you provide correct editor id? Is your editor registered in plugin xml?

Comment: You need to show us you code.

Comment: And while you're at it, you could add the rest of the exception behind "ModelServiceImpl.findElements(ModelServiceImp."

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your reply.. The problem I found was ,I was not setting the perspectiveID ..in the workbenchAdvisor class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Open an Editor using RCP Eclipse

```
package rcp_demo.Editor;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionEvent;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPage;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchWindow;
import org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException;
import org.eclipse.ui.handlers.HandlerUtil;

public class UserCommand extends AbstractHandler{

     public static final String ID = "rcp_demo.Editor.UserCommand";

    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {

         IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event);
            IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();
            //create UserEditorInput Class
            //public class UserEditorInput  implements IEditorInput{}
            UserEditorInput input = new UserEditorInput();
            try {
                //Create UserEditor class
                //public class UserEditor extends EditorPart {  public static final String ID = "rcp_demo.Editor.user";}
                page.openEditor(input, UserEditor.ID);

            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                System.out.println("Error:" + this.getClass().getName() + ":" + e);
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new ExecutionException("Error open UserEditor");
            }
        return null;
    }
}
```

> plugin.xml file
>
> perspectives id and perspectiveExtensions targetID are same like this

```
      // perspectives

      <extension
             point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectives">
          <perspective
                name="RCP Perspective"
                class="rcp_demo.Perspective"
                id="RCP_Demo.perspective">
          </perspective>
       </extension> 

    // perspectiveExtensions

     <extension
             point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">
          <perspectiveExtension
                targetID="RCP_Demo.perspective">
             <view
                   closeable="true"
                   id="RCP_Demo.Views.task"
                   minimized="false"
                   moveable="true"
                   relationship="right"
                   relative="org.eclipse.ui.editorss"
                   showTitle="true">
             </view>
               </perspectiveExtension>
       </extension>

     //User Command

      <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <command
            defaultHandler="rcp_demo.Editor.UserCommand"
            id="rcp_demo.Editor.UserCommand"
            name="Call UserEditor">
      </command>
     </extension>

    /// user Editor

       <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
      <editor
            class="rcp_demo.Editor.UserEditor"
            default="false"
            id="rcp_demo.Editor.user"
            name="UserEditor">
      </editor>
   </extension>
```